# Lagrangian method of interpolation with mathematica

Tags: methods, wolfram-mathematica, interpolation

I need to interpolate some data. I am using the function "interpolation". The problem is that this function just allows the spline or hermitian method. And It is not sufficient for my purpose.

I need something much more accurate: like lagrangian interpolation of order 31. Can anyone suggest a script or a particular command or mathematica options to do that?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Answer (score 0):

First off, Stack Exchange has a [dedicated Mathematica site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com). This might be better place to ask than Stack Overflow.

Next, so answer your question, [InterpolatingPolynomial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) is probably what you are looking for.

Lastly, that seems to be a *very* high order. To quote the Mathworld site 'a high-degree interpolation may be a poor predictor of the function between points, although the accuracy at the data points will be "perfect."' (link [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html)). This site has a link to the Mathematica workbook used in the example.